# Check if multi-line String contain only 2 numbers separated by 1 comma in Java

Tags: java, string, multiline

I have this code that gets a string written in a TextArea and passes it though a method (which allows multilines too):

```
 String ad = ady.getText();
    if (ad.matches("-?[0-9]+,-?[0-9]+") || ad.matches("-?[0-9]+,-?[0-9]+\n")) {
        String[] parts = ad.split(",");
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        if (num1 <= cl.size() && num1 > 0) {
            g.addCliente(nom, urba, street, ad);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Cliente inválido");
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Formato inválido");
    }
```

So as you can see, it already checks if the String follows a certain format "num1,num2" and num1 must be lower than size. how do i make it so it checks same format for every line in a TextArea and then passes it as: "Num1,Num2\nNum1,Num2\nNum1,Num2" with all the lines the user writes in the TextArea?

As you can see I tried adding \n at the end of ("-?[0-9]+,-?[0-9]+") and making it to be an OR if, but its not working.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your title asks about verifying a line has two numbers joined by a comma. Your code seems to accomplish that task. So why are you posting this Question?

Comment: did you read the stuff under the code?

Comment: Yes I did. Not clear. Example: “then passes it”, what passes what where? Are trying to generate text or parse text? Difficult to make heads or tails of this Question. I do not even see why you are using regex when simply parsing as numbers will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
    String nom = nombre.getText();
    String urba = urb.getText();
    String street = calle.getText();
    String ad = ady.getText();
    String[] lines = ad.split("\n");
    String adya = "";
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (line.matches("-?[0-9]+,-?[0-9]+")) {
            String[] parts = line.split(",");
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            //int num2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            if (num1 <= cl.size() && num1 > 0) {
                adya += line+"\n";
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Cliente inválido");
                return;
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Formato inválido");
            return;
        }
    }
    g.addCliente(nom, urba, street, adya.substring(0,adya.length()-1));
```

last line removes the last "\n" when passing it trough the method.